# ASP.NET API Windows authentication w/o login

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, roleprovider

Intranet application that needs to use Windows AD for authorization.  Anyone will have access to the site, but only members of a specific AD group will have access to certain pages and API calls.  The group name is in the web.config as it will vary by environment.  I want to be able to use attributes on API controllers and methods:

```
 [MyAdminAttribute]
 public class MyController : ApiController
```

Here is my custom attribute:

```
public class MyAdminAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var user = ((ApiController)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).User;  // THIS USER IS ALWAYS NULL, WHY?
        var adminGroup = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAdminGroup"];
        var isInAdminGroup = user.IsInRole(adminGroup);
        var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value).ToList();  // Just checking here, 0 roles found.

        return isInAdminGroup;
    }
}
```

I also need to be able to check that the user is in the role within a Razor view:

```
 @if (User.IsInRole(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAdminGroup"])) {
```

Here are the relevent web.config settings:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
 <providers>
    <clear />
    <add 
        name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
        applicationName="/" />
 </providers>
</roleManager>
```

However, the User is always null and User.IsInRole() is always false.  Why would this be occuring?

Comment: The web server isn't configured for windows auth.  Users have to log in (IE users may not, but chrome and other users will) prior to accessing the website.  Once they log in, User will be populated correctly.  IIRC, it's called NTLM in iis.

Comment: I have this problem running locally.  Is there something I can do to get it to work when debugging?  Maybe an IISExpress configuration?

Comment: Yep.  Not sure what it is, unfortunately.  Research turning on NTLM for IISExpress.  Probably going to be some settings you can throw in web.config to get it working.